# Cifrado Cesar, solo MAYUSCULAS

Tags: c++

Tengo este programa, quisiera que lo que se imprima sea Mayusculas independientemente lo que reciba (MAYUS o minus). Esta casi listo solo me falta que imprima en mayusculas.

Como ven imprimo mi void en el main, pero quiero que imprima mi void en MAYUSCULAS.
Ejemplo

Hola mundo. (con desplazamiento 3)

KROD PXQGR

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



void encriptar(char secreto[], int);



int main(){
    char secreto[1000];
    int n;
    cin.getline(secreto, 1000);
    cin >> n;
    
    encriptar(secreto, n);
    
    cout<< secreto;
    
    return 0;
}

void encriptar(char secreto[], int n){
    int i, j;
    char abecedario []= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    if(n>0 && n<27){
        for(i=0; secreto[i]; i++){
            j=0;
            for(j=0; j<52; j++){
                if(secreto[i]==abecedario[j] && j<78){
                    secreto[i]=abecedario[j+n];
                    j=52;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Estaría bien que, antes de seguir enviando preguntas, revises todas las que ya has hecho y marques alguna respuesta como aceptada (o pongas tu solución y la marques para compartirla con los demás). La comunidad entiende por tu historial actual que no estás muy interesado en aportar.

Comment: Disculpa, es que no usar muy bien esta plataforma.

Comment: por favor, hace el [tour] y tambien mira [ask]. La seccion respuestas es solo para respuestas a la pregunta, no es para hacer nuevas preguntas ni un seguimiento de la realizada.

Comment: Ademas,si se fijan en las otras preguntas. Praticamente yo solo termine los programas y en todo caso, MI APORTE FUE ENVIARLO RESUELTO CON CASOS NO EXPUESTOS AQUI.

Comment: Amigo, piensa que otros pueden tener tu misma pregunta, tu mismo problema, así como viniste tú. La idea es que otros vengan en el futuro, mañana o en un año, y puedan resolver su duda sabiendo lo que ahora tú sabes. Si consideras que eso no tiene valor, los demás no estaremos tan inclinados a responder tus preguntas.

Comment: Por eso comparto cuando realizo el programa :/

Comment: Oye el sitio no funciona así, tenias una duda de como pasar las letras a mayúsculas. Si quitas tu pregunta poniendo un ejemplo de como codificar en cesar, le quitas lo bueno que pudiste hacer. Si alguien tiene la misma duda que tu, no encontrara la pregunta util. Si quieres compartir tu solucion, puedes hacerlo perfectamente en las respuestas. Podrias, porfavor,  volver a colocar la pregunta, y mover tu solucion a los comentarios?

Comment: ok @Pablochaches  Esta hecho.

Comment: @MarcoMolina Gracias a ti. Lo mejor que podemos hacer es pensar en los que en un futuro tendrán las mismas dudas que nosotros

Comment: Revertí la última edición, que eliminaba el texto publicado en la pregunta, sin embargo, al leerla, aún el texto de la pregunta no hace sentido. Creo que @Marco no ha comprendido el funcionamiento del sitio. La idea es que quede una pregunta, con las respuestas que ha podido obtener de la comunidad y, dentro de estas, la respuesta que mejor sirvió al AP para resolver su problema. No hace falta editar la pregunta para decir que se resolvió ni para hacer comentarios sobre consideraciones filosóficas del AP. Este es un sitio técnico y tanto la pregunta como las respuestas deben limitarse a ello.

Comment: Por lo mismo sugiero que edites la pregunta y la dejes en buena forma exponiendo cuál era tu problema, para que las respuestas que has obtenido tengan sentido. Este conocimiento quedará aquí, a espera de ser de utilidad para alguna persona que llegue aquí en el futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peticion de un miembro de la comunidad puse la respuesta a mi duda en la parte de respuestas. Esperando pueda ser de utilidad.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



void encriptar(char secreto[], int);



int main(){
    char secreto[1000];
    int n;
    cin.getline(secreto, 1000);
    cin >> n;
    
    encriptar(secreto, n);
    
    cout<< secreto;
    
    return 0;
}

void encriptar(char secreto[], int n){
    int i, j;
    char abecedarioT []= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char abecedariominus []="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
    char abecedarioMAYUS []="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    if(n>0 && n<27){
        for(i=0; secreto[i]; i++){
            j=0;
        if (secreto[i] >= 'a' && secreto[i] <= 'z' || secreto[i] >= 'A' && secreto[i] <= 'Z') {
            for(j=0; j<78; j++){
                if(secreto[i]==abecedarioT[j] && j<78){
                    secreto[i]=abecedarioMAYUS[j+n];
                    j=78;
                }
                if (secreto[i]==abecedariominus[j] && j<78){ 
                    secreto[i]=abecedarioMAYUS[j+n];
                    j=78;       
                }
                if (secreto[i]==abecedarioMAYUS[j] && j<78){ 
                    secreto[i]=abecedarioMAYUS[j+n];
                    j=78;   
                }
            }
       }    
    }   
    }
    
    else
    {
        for(i=0; secreto[i]; i++){
            j=0;
        if (secreto[i] >= 'a' && secreto[i] <= 'z' || secreto[i] >= 'A' && secreto[i] <= 'Z') {
            for(j=0; j<78; j++){
                if(secreto[i]==abecedarioT[j] && j<78){
                    secreto[i]=abecedarioMAYUS[j];
                    j=78;
                }
                if (secreto[i]==abecedariominus[j] && j<78){ 
                    secreto[i]=abecedarioMAYUS[j];
                    j=78;       
                }
                if (secreto[i]==abecedarioMAYUS[j] && j<78){ 
                    secreto[i]=abecedarioMAYUS[j];
                    j=78;   
                }
                
                
           }
        }   
        
        }   
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para pasarlos todos a mayúsculas puedes usar la función `toupper` en todos los caracteres. Esta recibe un carácter y lo devuelve hecho mayusula.

```cpp
   for (int i=0; secreto[i]; i++) {
        secreto[i] = toupper(secreto[i]);
    }
```

Aqui esta ya puesto en el codigo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



void encriptar(char secreto[], int);



int main(){
    char secreto[1000];
    int n;
    cin.getline(secreto, 1000);
    cin >> n;
    
    encriptar(secreto, n);
    
    for (int i=0; secreto[i]; i++) {
        secreto[i] = toupper(secreto[i]);
    }
    
    cout<< secreto;
    
    return 0;
}

void encriptar(char secreto[], int n){
    int i, j;
    char abecedario []= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    if(n>0 && n<27){
        for(i=0; secreto[i]; i++){
            j=0;
            for(j=0; j<52; j++){
                if(secreto[i]==abecedario[j] && j<78){
                    secreto[i]=abecedario[j+n];
                    j=52;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

---

---

#### Otros

Se que tu pregunta no va de esto, pero es para avisarte que tienes un pequeño bug en tu codigo. Prueba darle como entrada

```
ZZZ
1
```

Y no saca nada

Le das esto como entrada:

```
HHHHHHHHHHH
25
```

Te da como resultado:

```
66666666666
```

Tienes que revisar que los resultados se mantengan en los limites.

Otra cosita es que este pedazo de codigo:

```
            for(j=0; j<52; j++){
                if(secreto[i]==abecedario[j] && j<78){
                    secreto[i]=abecedario[j+n];
                    j=52;
            }
```

Ver si es una letra de ese modo es muy lento. Un código equivalente haciendo podría ser este:

```
if (secreto[i] >= 'a' && secreto[i] <= 'z' || secreto[i] >= 'A' && secreto[i] <= 'Z') {
    secreto[i] += n;
}
```

Sin importar cual uses, lo que tienes que hacer es mantener los resultados entre `a` y `z`  & `A` y `Z`

Comment: Hola, ya pude realizarlo. Voy a editar mi pregunta; pero igual, muchas gracias. Tu aporte de simplificar el for es muy buenoo.